# Magento2 : Override Admin Js file

Tags: magento2, javascript, adminhtml, overrides

I am working on Magento 2.1 CE. My current active Theme is the Default LUMA Theme

I wish to override the CORE Modules "bundle-input-type.js" located in "vendor\magento\module-bundle\view\adminhtml\web\js\components\bundle-input-type.js"

Can someone give me a detailed stepwise procedure to do the same ?

Online articles do not seem to help me much.